# PySimpleGUI output window

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm using PySimpleGUI to create GUIs in Python.
I use the following parameters to create a window:

```
creditionals, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True, keep_on_top = True, alpha_channel=.9
```

and everything works normally, but when I use these options for output window opacity parameter gives me error:

```
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
sg.Print('Starting Process...', do_not_reroute_stdout=False, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True, keep_on_top = True, alpha_channel=.9)
```

Without alpha_channel option output window generates normally, however with it error is occurring.
If anyone has an idea about its solution, I would like to consider it.

Comment: There's no option `alpha_channel` for function `sg.Print` or `sg.easy_print`, please refer document at [Debug Window Output](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#debug-window-output). The `_DebugWin` is a private class and you cannot access it, so you can create one window with a `sg.multiline` by yourself if necessary.

Comment: Ok, I'll try sg.multiline. Thanks